# Consume wcf secured self hosted service in Silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

I've created a ssl/https web service that is hosted in a console application.

For 127.0.0.1:8741 I've added a certificate and I use https://127.0.0.1:8741/MagazinService/ as endpoint. I use Visual Studio Web Development Server for the Silverlight 4 client. Also the console application that hosts the web service is launched from Visual Studio. I do not use IIS at all. I successfully added the service reference to the silverlight client but when I call operations from the server I get a cross domain error.

I have read about clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml and added this files in the whole solution and it does not work.

I am stuck! Please help! Here is the code that I use:

The app.config in the console application (the server/host):

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MagazinServiceBehavior" name="SOAP.MagazinVirtual">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MagazinServiceBinding" contract="SOAP.IMagazinVirtual">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://127.0.0.1:8741/MagazinService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <!-- buffer: 64KB; max size: 64MB -->
    <binding name="MagazinServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpsTransport>
      </httpsTransport>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MagazinServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <add scheme="https" port="443" />
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SOAP.Validator, SOAP" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

here

The ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_IMagazinVirtual">
                <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="true">
                    <secureConversationBootstrap />
                </security>
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://127.0.0.1:8741/MagazinService/" binding="customBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IMagazinVirtual" contract="ServiceReference.IMagazinVirtual"
            name="CustomBinding_IMagazinVirtual" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here is the code from the silverlight web project , Web.config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_IMagazinVirtual">
                <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
                    requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Strict" includeTimestamp="true"
                    keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
                    <localClientSettings cacheCookies="true" detectReplays="false"
                        replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00" maxCookieCachingTime="Infinite"
                        replayWindow="00:05:00" sessionKeyRenewalInterval="10:00:00"
                        sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00" reconnectTransportOnFailure="true"
                        timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" cookieRenewalThresholdPercentage="60" />
                    <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" issuedCookieLifetime="10:00:00"
                        maxStatefulNegotiations="128" replayCacheSize="900000" maxClockSkew="00:05:00"
                        negotiationTimeout="00:01:00" replayWindow="00:05:00" inactivityTimeout="00:02:00"
                        sessionKeyRenewalInterval="15:00:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:05:00"
                        reconnectTransportOnFailure="true" maxPendingSessions="128"
                        maxCachedCookies="1000" timestampValidityDuration="00:05:00" />
                    <secureConversationBootstrap />
                </security>
                <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    maxSessionSize="2048">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </binaryMessageEncoding>
                <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://127.0.0.1:8741/MagazinService/" binding="customBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IMagazinVirtual" contract="ServiceReference.IMagazinVirtual"
            name="CustomBinding_IMagazinVirtual" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is the code for clientaccesspolicy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
     <policy>
       <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
         <domain uri="http://*" />
        <domain uri="https://*" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true" />
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

And this is the code for crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction" secure="true" />
 </cross-domain-policy>
```

I am having a hard time with this, please help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a service which can return that xml when a call to the filename at the root of your site is made, as this is what silverlight will do.

When hosted in IIS having the actual file is enough as IIS will serve it when the request to host.name.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml is made.  when self hosting this won't be done by default so you need to add stuff to ensure that when this call is made the xml is returned correctly.

create a service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICrossDomainService
    {
    [WebGet (UriTemplate = "clientaccesspolicy.xml")]
    Stream ProvidePolicyFile ();

    [WebGet (UriTemplate = "crossdomain.xml")]
    Stream ProvideDomainFile ();
    }
```

then an implementation:

```
public class CrossDomainService : ICrossDomainService
    {
    #region ICrossDomainService Members

    public Stream ProvidePolicyFile ()
        {
        string result =
            @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers=""*"">
        <domain uri=""*""/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource include-subpaths=""true"" path=""/""/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>";

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/xml";

        return new MemoryStream (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (result));
        }

    public Stream ProvideDomainFile ()
        {
        string result =
            @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM ""http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd"">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain=""*"" />
</cross-domain-policy>";

        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/xml";

        return new MemoryStream (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (result));
        }

    #endregion
    }
```

Then host the implementation at the root of your site:

```
  <service name="CrossDomainService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="CrossDomainServiceBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="ICrossDomainService"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>


  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CrossDomainServiceBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
```

This works for me in a self hosted environment

Comment: Ok, I created this new service. What do I have to do now ? Do I have to add a service reference to my silverlight client pointing to the new created service? Do I need to call the methods from CrossDomainService? The first service, the secured one, is on https://127.0.0.1:8741 and the one I created now is listening on http://localhost:8732. Is it ok like this?

Comment: I added the reference to the new created service. Now it seems that the completed event is fired after calling a method from the secured service but I still have the same cross domain exception. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: you shouldn't need to do anything.  They should both be running on the same port I think.  Try changing the cross domain service to run on 8741.

Comment: can you browse to http://localhost:8741/crossdomain.xml and see the xml?  you should be able to if the service is being hosted correctly

Comment: If I browse http://localhost:8732/crossdomain.xml I can see the xml file, but if I change the port from 8732 to 8741, same port as the secured service, it gives me an exception saying that it cannot register http to listen on 8741 because it is in use.

Comment: We are not using secured services, but we have both services running on the same port...  Are both services hosted ion the same self-hosted service?  or do you have seperate hosts for each service?

Comment: I have initialized a ServiceHost class for each type of the service. This two instances are opened in the main method of the console application.